# Can't paint an image after choosing it from JFileChooser

Tags: image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

Good evening. I have read a lot of topics here on stackoverflow or even internet but I can't find the solution to my problem.

I have an interface like this:
[image]

When I click on "Load Image A", I can choose the image that I want. Next I want to paint this image under the JLabel **"Image A"**. But it doesn't want to show up.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
package projet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MonPanelImage extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8267224342030244581L;
    private BufferedImage image; 

    public MonPanelImage(File adresse)
    {
        try{
            image = ImageIO.read(adresse);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        System.out.println("paint");
        if(image != null){
             g.drawImage(image, 20, 20, this);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is where I call it:

```
    //panel image. This is my second panel which will be for the images
    final JPanel second = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    //panel button. This is the third panel for the buttons
    rows = 0;
    cols = 3;
    hgap = 5;
    vgap = 0;
    JPanel third = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows,cols,hgap,vgap));     
    //buttons
    JButton boutonLoad1 = new JButton("Load image A");
    boutonLoad1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int retour = fc.showDialog(frame, "Charger l'image");
            if(retour == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){              
                String pathImage1 = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                path1 = pathImage1; 

                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                MonPanelImage panelImage1 = new MonPanelImage(file);
                second.add(panelImage1, BorderLayout.WEST);
                second.revalidate();
                second.repaint();
            }
        }
    });
```

At the very end, i add the 3 panels to my frame and set the frame to visible.
But I can't paint an image. Maybe I'm not doing it properly. Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
super.paintComponents(g);
```

First of all it should be `super.paintComponent(g)`, without the `"s"`.

```
second.add(panelImage1, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

You are adding your image to a component using a BorderLayout. The BorderLayout will respect the width of your component, which is 0, so there is nothing to paint.

Whenever, you do custom painting you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of your component so the layout manager can do its job.

However, an easier solution is to just use a `JLabel` with an `Icon`. There is no need to do custom painting when you are painting the image at its real size.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried to use JLAbel with an Icon like this:JLabel picLabel = new JLabel("", new ImageIcon(pathImage1), JLabel.CENTER);
           second.add(picLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
           second.revalidate(); And it didn't work either (sorry, I don't know how to make the typo for the code here)

Comment: Is your file name correct? It looks to me like you are just getting the file name and not the path to the file. Add a display statement to your code to verify the path you are using. If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. I use JLabels with Icons all the time without problem.

Comment: what is a [SSCCE]() ? sorry to ask

Comment: Just edited my comment. I hit enter before I meant to.